# CORS request issue (Preflight success, request not)

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, cors

## Description

API is .NET 6 application. Frontend on latest stable React.
Confugre CORS on backend-side by following code:

```
...
builder.Services.AddCors();

...
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(x => x
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
    .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials

app.UseAuthorization();
```

On frontend side configure axios instance by following code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://domain.name/',
  timeout: 15000,
  withCredentionals: true
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

## Problem

Then we send POST request. Firstly screenshot from preflight headers response
[image]
Receive 204 (No Content) status - it's ok!
Then application send second part of request and we receive "CORS missing Allow Origin"
With following headers:
[image]

In backend endpoint code i force appending headers in response by this:

```
 Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
 Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
 Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
```

Comment: According to the "Volterra" headers, there's a load balancer in between, probably stripping/modifying/adding the relevant headers. Configure that device/application.

Comment: Where i can find this balancer? In backend only 1 controller without attributes (except Route, HttpPost and ApiController), 1 extension which not related with requests/responses at all and program.cs

Comment: Ask your system administrator, I don't know how you host this.

Comment: But you can ask me. 
We host BE and FE as separated IIS Sites on Windows Server.

Comment: Again, according to the screenshot of the response headers, there's an f5 Volterra proxy/loadbalancer in front of that, which is stripping or modifying the headers your application returns. If you don't know how to configure that loadbalancer, you need to ask someone who does.

Comment: I don't think you can use wildcards when allow credentials is true either: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials